# Como executar função em Python a cada 1 minuto, sem usar time.sleep()

Tags: python, datetime

É possível executar uma função a cada 1 minuto sem usar o time.sleep()?
Eu preciso usar o relógio do computador para que, sempre quando o relógio atingir 1 minuto, a função seja executada.
O time.sleep() não serviu porque ficou difícil sincronizar o início do programa no instante 0:00 para que o intervalo de tempo de 60segundos coincidisse com o do relógio.

tentei esse código:

```
while True:
    agora = datetime.datetime.now()
    segundo = agora.strftime('%S')
    if segundo == '00':
        print(agora)
```

Depois tentei esse outro código, mas também sem sucesso:

```
while True:
    agora = datetime.datetime.now()
    hora = agora.strftime('%M:%S')
    zero = ['1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00', '5:00', '6:00', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00', '0:00']
    if agora in zero:
        print(agora)
```

Comment: Já viu o módulo [Sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html)?

Comment: entre as chamadas das funçõe agendadas você vai rodar alguma coisa? (inclusive se tiver uma interface gráfica  como tkinter, isso é considerado "rodar alguma coisa")

Answer (score 2):

Como o @JassRiver colocou ali - pode ser usado o módulo `sched` da biblioteca padrão - mas só essa dica pode não ser suficiente, já que o "sched" é bem baixo nível e flexível - então exige que se construa um pouco de código "em volta" para funcionar bem -

Então, pra começar, o construtor `sched.schedule` pede como parâmetros as funções de pausa e de dizer o horário - tudo o que ele faz é, uma vez que é chamado o método "run" dele - ele vai chamando as funções de pause e verificar o horário e chamando os eventos agendados. A forma mais simples de usa-lo é passar as funções `time.time` e `time.pause` para o Scheduler - e isso implica que você vai ter que agendar os eventos usando a unidade de tempo usada pelo "time.time" - que é um único número inteiro representando o número de segundos transcorridos desde a 0h00 de 1 de janeiro de 1970.

Para agendar minutos, então temos que usar o módulo datetime do Python para converter os minutos redondos nesses "unix timestamp" - e aí agendar um evento para cada minuto.

Além disso, depois que chamar o ".run", o scheduler vai ficar chamando o "time.sleep" e o seu programa não vai fazer mais nada. Isso pode ser remediado se chamarmos o ".run()" do scheduler em outra thread.

Vou montar um exemplo mínimo aqui - ...

```py
import sched
import time
import threading
from datetime import datetime


def repeat_at_interval(scheduler, event, interval=60, add_n=10, start_t=None):
    """Adds 'add_n' more calls to "event" at each "interval" seconds"""
    # Unix timestamp
    if start_t is None:
        t = time.time()
        # round to next interval -
        t = t - (t % interval) + interval
    else:
        t = start_t

    for i in range(add_n):
        scheduler.enterabs(t, 0, event)
        t += interval

    # Schedule call to self, to add "add_n" extra events
    # when these are over:
    scheduler.enterabs(t - interval, 0, repeat_at_interval, kwargs={
        "scheduler": scheduler,
        "event": event,
        "interval": interval,
        "add_n": add_n,
        "start_t": t
        })


def test():
    print (datetime.now())

def main():
    scheduler  = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    repeat_at_interval(scheduler, test, interval=60)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=scheduler.run)
    thread.start()
    while True:

        time.sleep(10)
        # Qualquer outro código para rodar em paralelo,
        # pode ficar aqui -
        # as tarefas agendadas são chamadas em outra
        # thread
        print("controle")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note que fiz as contas apra as chamadas sem usar o módulo datetime, que permite fazer contas usando "hora, minuto, segundo, dia do mes, mes, ano" - etc -- e uso direto o time.time() - perceba que se pego o resto da divisão de "time.time()" por 60, tenho o timestamp do último minuto redondo (contando desde o "epoch" 1970-1-1 00.00) -e a partir daí, se vou somando sempre "60" nesse valor, vou tendo os outros minutos.

Usar o timestamp assim faz com que o código não precise fazer "contas"  e "ifs" para as viradas de hora, de dia, de data, etc...
(se eu estivesse usando objetos 'datetime', poderia, pra calcular o horario do proximo minuto fazer `proximo = previo.replace(minute = previo.minuto + 1)` - mas aí teria que levar em conta todas as mudanças - no minuto 59, na hora 23, no dia 31, etc...)

Outra coisa legal desse código é que em vez de adicionar "um milhão" de chamadas de uma vez, ele cria 10, e chama a própria função que agenda eventos ao final desses 10 - e aí agenda mais 10.
Se você estivesse usando um framework que permite agendar um callback para daqui a "x segundos", como o tkinter, pyglet, pyqt, etc... em geral o próprio evento "se agenda" de volta. Essa função permite que o seu evento não tenha que se preocupar com isso.

Comment: Excelente. Eu não conhecia o módulo sched, mas já comecei a estudá-lo. Sua resposta abriu minhas possibilidades.

Comment: deve ser fácil achar bibliotecas externas que tem tudo isso pronto também-  desculpe não ter citado.